# How to set up OpenSSH to use x509 PKI for authentication?

Tags: authentication, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, x.509

I do not mean simply putting the public RSA key of a x.509 certificate into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - I'm looking for a way to set up a ssh such that x.509 certificates signed by a pre-defined CA will automatically be granted access to the linked user account. [RFC 6187](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6187) seems to suggest such a functionality, but I can't find any documentation on this, or whether it is implemented in OpenSSH at all.

Here's a more elaborate description of what I want to do:

- A CA ("SSH-CA") is set up
- This CA is used to sign user certificates with `keyUsage=digitalSignature` (and maybe the `id-kp-secureShellClient` extendedKeyUsage field)
- This certificate can now be used to log in on a server. The server does not require the public key being present in the `authorized_keys`. Instead, it is set up to trust the SSH-CA to verify the public key and signature of the certificate (or certificate chain) and the username/UID (probably directly in the `subjectAltName` field, or maybe using some server-side mapping) before the usual RSA authentication takes place

So, (how) can this be achieved with OpenSSH, and if it requires a patch how can client-side modifications be kept minimal?

---

As an alternative I guess one could also use any S/MIME certificate plus a username to email-address mapping, without requiring an own CA. The client could also still use only the private RSA key and a certificate server is used obtain a certificate from a public key, additionally offering the possibility to use PGP certificates as well (e.g. via [monkeysphere](http://web.monkeysphere.info/why/#index2h2)) without the user requiring any knowledge about all this as long as they simply provide a public key.

If it's not natively possible, I guess I could come up with a semi-automatic "implementation" of this by letting a script on the server automatically check a somehow else submitted certificate via `openssl` (or `gnupg`) and have the public key be put to the respective user's `authorized_keys` file - although at that point I *am* probably more or less re-doing the [monkeyshere project](http://web.monkeysphere.info/why/#index2h2)...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

OpenSSH does not officially support x.509 certificate based authentication:

> The developers have maintained a stance that the complexity of X.509 
>   certificates introduces an unacceptable attack surface for sshd. 
>   Instead, they have [recently] implemented an alternative certificate 
>   format which is much simpler to parse and thus introduces less risk.

...

> OpenSSH just uses the low-level cryptographic algorithms from 
>   OpenSSL.

However [Roumen Petrov publishes OpenSSH builds that do include X.509 support](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/), and you could try with those.

> X.509 certificates can [be] used as "user identity" and/or "host key" in
>   SSH "Public Key" and "Host-Based" authentications.

Roumen Petrov's builds can be downloaded [via this page](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/download.html).

[Here's a Debian how-to for SSH with authentication key instead of password](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724191303/https://debian-administration.org/articles/530) that might also prove useful in setting up your OpenSSH to accept x509 PKI for user authentication.

Comment: The Debian link is just about the usual key setup, but Roumen Petrov's build sounds like the solution

Comment: Please be careful with Roumen Petrov's build and [**do not** reuse](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-reuse) the same x509 certificate for ssl/https. Bugs like [3-Shake](https://www.mitls.org/pages/attacks/3SHAKE) show that it is hard to use crypto securely within just the SSL protocol. Security of SSH implementations is never tested in this SSH-SSL key-reuse scenario!

Answer (score 31):

Native certificate-based authentication is available in unmodified upstream OpenSSH. It is not, however, based on x.509.

First, generate your CA:

```
ssh-keygen -f ssh-ca
```

Next, install your CA key in `.authorized_keys` with a `cert-authority` prefix:

```
echo "cert-authority $(<ssh-ca.pub)" >>.ssh/authorized_keys
```

From that point, whenever a key is generated by a user:

```
ssh-keygen -f real-key
```

...the public portion can be signed by your SSH CA, whereafter it will be trusted by the server without that key itself being added to `authorized_keys`:

```
ssh-keygen -s ssh-ca -I identifier_for_your_real_key_goes_here real-key.pub
```

Comment: Thanks, I never read about this despite it being available since apparently 5.4 from 2011... https://github.com/cloudtools/ssh-ca might be of interest then. I'll try and check this sometime, in which case you'd deserve the checkmark

Comment: Absolutely incredible! I'm surprised I've never seen this done before!

Comment: It works for `known_hosts` too; one can put a CA in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` for one's own domain, sign the host keys on the various servers with that CA, and then never again have a prompt asking a user to manually verify (or, more realistically, punt on manually verifying and assume) that a given host key for a server in that domain is valid.

Comment: (Of course, one needs to be able to distribute updates to that `ssh_known_hosts` with revocations for compromised host keys, but... them's the breaks).

Comment: I believe this answer provides OpenSSH certificate format, and not X.509 certificate format. X.509 certificate format is detailed in RFC 6187. Also see [ssh-keygen and writing user certificate in X.509 format?](https://superuser.com/q/1459811/173513) on SuperUser.

Comment: @jww, yes, the very first paragraph of this answer says that it's not based on X.509. (That said, the OP's stated workflow doesn't require anything about X.509 except insofar as it's couched in X.509-specific terminology; the native OpenSSH format still makes all the functionality they request available, just under different names -- and as the first comment on this answer implies, they weren't aware of non-X.509-based certificates as an option when writing the question).

Answer (score 3):

With OpenSSH it's not possible. As said by @TildalWave you need to use the fork from Roumen Petrov [PKIXSSH](https://roumenpetrov.info/secsh).

Once you have your X509 certificate **you don't need to add the public key** on the `authorized_keys` file.

You need to configure two things in the **server side**:

- **Add the certificate for the CA** in the directory set by `CACertificatePath` directive in `sshd_config` file (normally `/etc/ssh/ca/crt`, I think) with a link for the hash of the certificate.

  For creating the link use openssl. Supposing the CA certificate has been copied under `/ect/ssh/ca/crt/ca.crt` the commands will be:

```
cd /etc/ssh/ca/crt/
ln -s ca.crt `openssl x509 -in ca.crt -noout -hash`.0
```

- Add the **"subject" information of x509 certificate to the `authorized_keys` file** of the user *(in destination server)*

  Suppose the private key and the X509 certificate of the user is in `ssh/id_rsa` to get the subject run in the client:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in .ssh/id_rsa
```

And them on the server, add this line with the prefix `x509v3-sign-rsa subject=` to the `authorized_keys`.

This line will have a content similar to this one:

```
x509v3-sign-rsa subject= /C=ES/ST=Pontevedra/L=Vigo/CN=testssh/emailAddress=josemanuel@ciges.net
```

As we can see, the authentication is really made **trusting the CA for any valid x509 certificate from the user**. We could generate a new certificate and it will be accepted with no intervention on server side.

---

After struggling for a few days I have written a post explaining the full process on a blog I have just deployed. You can read it at ["OpenSSH with X509 certificates HOW TO"](http://tech.ciges.net/blog/openssh-with-x509-certificates-how-to/).

Answer (score 1):

**CA Signed SSH keys**

When you want to manage user's access out-of-bound, then you don't want to install their public key in authorized_keys files on the servers they need to access. Neither do you want to manage personal accounts, but instead use a principal (functional account i.e. admin) and grant a lease on it.

You can create a Certificate Signing Authority for Secure Shell (different from X509 TLS/SSL) simply by creating an ssh keypair. The CA's public key is installed on all servers, and that is the only file that needs to be there. (You can have 2 CA keys in the file or more if you need.)

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/ca_ssh
cat ~/.ssh/ca_ssh.pub
```

Copy this file to the servers and add it to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/trusted-user-ca-keys.pub
```

**Granting Access**

To sign Fred's public key (fred.pub) to grant one week access to the server as admin and log as staff in /var/log/secure, run this command and send the fred.pub-cert file back to Fred.

```
ssh-keygen -s ~/.ssh/ca_ssh -I staff -n admin -V +1w fred.pub
```

**Revoking keys**

Add public keys of people that should no longer login during their lease to `playbook_dir/files/ssh/revoked_keys`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not possible. And there is strong reasons for that. But if you want to achieve you can use tool which I developed on top of socat. It is almost full featured terminal access over pty and use x509. I do plan to extend it and make much more sophisticated.

https://github.com/aze2201/shell_sock

Comment: Could you please kindly elaborate how the software helps out/solves the problem of OP?

Comment: OP means OpenSSH ? This is using invoke /bin/bash ,pty parameter to remote socat, with forward to raw TCP. but connection esablishes with OpenSSL connection via x509.

Comment: in nutshel.. client uses socat openssl connection with key, crt, ca-cert to server socat which listens openssl own key,crt and same ca-key. Once connection establishes client send port request to server and server redirect to local port in proxy via socat.

Comment: admin can connect to proxy and listen nc over ssh in proxy. all connections are secure

Comment: please edit your answer accordingly, thank you