# Managing and storing lots of SSH keys in the cloud

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, key-management

I have a pool of cloud servers (~50) that need to talk to many other remote cloud servers (~4000) using SSH. Each remote server has its own SSH key, so we need a place to store all of these remote servers' SSH keys securely. How should we go about storing these keys without saving them all over?

What is the best way to securely store lots of SSH keys in one place and make our servers ask for them at run-time?

Comment: I took out the product recommendation bit. It's generally not allowed on a Stackexchange site.

Comment: For others finding this question many years later, I suspect this is a good solution: https://serverfault.com/a/653793/88188

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to make important distinctions: there are *public keys* and *private keys*. When "stored securely", they call for different notions of "securely".

Each SSH server owns a public/private key pair. Each server should generate its own key pair, and the private key should *never* leave the server itself. The public key is *public*, meaning that everybody can learn it. When you connect to the server, that's one of the first things that the server tells you: its public key. It *shouts* it all over the network. When dealing with SSH public keys and their storage, the question is really that of **integrity**: a given SSH client must *remember* the public keys of all the servers that it wants to talk to (the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file with usual Linux SSH clients); the attacker may want to include a fake public key in there, in order to run a fake server.

Each SSH client *may* own a public/private key pair: such a key pair will be used for client authentication by the server. If you use password-based client authentication, then the clients don't have such key pairs. If you use key-based client authentication, then each server must know the public keys of "authorized clients" (the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` for Linux SSH implementations).

In your case, you have 50 SSH clients talking to 4000 SSH servers. Therefore, using the normal SSH model, you would have to ensure that:

- Each of the 50 clients knows a copy of the public keys for all 4000 servers.
- If using key-based client authentication, each of the 4000 servers must know a copy of the 50 client public keys.

Given these figures, the relevant files will be bulky, and key management will be a problem (if you add a new client, the new client's public key must be imported into 4000 servers, with protected integrity). [Public-Key Infrastructures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure) were invented to solve that problem. A raw, "official" [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) instance does not know how to use X.509 certificates; however, a [modified version](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/) exists (see also [that previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30396/how-to-set-up-openssh-to-use-x509-pki-for-authentication)). With an X.509-aware SSH code base, you could run your own *Certification Authority* (e.g. the open-source [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/)), and issue certificates for your clients and servers. That way, SSH client and servers will send each other their certificates when needed, dynamically. Each machine will only have to store its own private key and certificate, and also "know" the CA certificate (in the relevant "trust store"). Adding a new client or a new server to the mix then is just issuing a certificate, and the management problem is solved (or, rather, *moved around*: now you have a PKI to handle).

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for a configuration management software like Puppet, Chef, etc. It was created to handle exactly this kinds of problems. I strongly recommend you use configuration management software if you have so many servers.

Comment: Really my question is around the security of it and not configuration automation of it. How do we go about storing the keys in a secure way.

Comment: With Puppet, you can configure it so only the private key used by that machine (to access other machines) is present. This allows you to have all private keys present on the Puppet server with each individual server having only its own private key.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to the part about storing keys securely one option is to store the private keys in an HSM (hardware security module). There are a few well known vendors that offer these but there are alternatives. See for example [Cryptostick](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/02/13/using-cryptostick-as-an-hsm/).

The advantage of using an HSM is that the private keys can only be used while the hardware device is present on the system and one cannot copy the private keys elsewhere.

This type of solution would also require proper auditing and management of authorized SSH keys on the SSH servers. Otherwise nothing would prevent an intruder of generating and placing their own set of keys in the SSH server.

Managing those keys however, is a problem. There are commercial products out there for managing SSH keys but I'm not aware of any good open source solution.

As Thomas said one option is moving to a PKI based approach, however this would require updating all your SSH clients and servers.

*Disclaimer: I work for a company that sells a commercial SSH key management product.*

Answer (score 1):

SSH has its own way to solve this with signed keys, you don't need X509, nor do you need to distribure public keys in various places. You typically create a couple of CA signing keys for host keys and user keys and configure servers and clients to only trust the CA. With short-lived certificates and principals the servers can have a write-once/read-only configuration.

Read more in the manual section CERTIFICATES in `man 1 ssh-keygen`.

Comment: _OpenSSH_, which is a good and popular implementation, does this, but it's an extension -- it's not in the standard SSH protocol and may not work with (or on) other implementations.

Answer (score -3):

Consider some ssh key management software that can store and dynamically manage (change) ssh keys, this is directly analogous to a password management system.

However these solutions come at a cost !